# Overwriting XML file from CSV via Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am new to Powershell scripting.

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have an XML file:

```
<vehicle>
    <brand model="Corola">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country> 
    <year>2021<year>

    <brand model="RAV4">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2021<year>
  
    
    <brand model="camry">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2019<year>

    <brand model="Sienna">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2016<year>

</vehicle>
```

I wrote a script that exports the model names with their relative xpaths.

The exported CSV looks like this:

[image].

Now, I want to change the model names via the CSV file and create a new XML file with the updated values via Powershell.
The changed CSV file looks like this:
[image].

This is my script, and the problem is that the iteration changes only on the last iteration.

I changed my script a little, and save the updates on each iteration (which is not ideal, but still doesn't work).

Here's my code:

```
function ReplaceValues {
  
    $fileToChange = Read-Host('Please prrovide the XML file path')
    $newFile = New-Object XML
    
    # new xml file is created, this file needs to be updated with the new values 
    $newFile.Load($fileToChange);

    #provideing the path on the local enviornment to save the updated file
    $updatedFilePath = Read-Host('Please provide local path for the updated file')

    #giving a name to the new XML file on the local enviornment
    $updatedFileName = Read-Host('Please name the updated file')

    #saving the new file in my local
    $newFile.save("$updatedFilePath\$updatedFileName.xml")

    #providing the path of the CSV file with the updated values
    $csvFilePath = Read-Host('Please provide the full path of the csv File')

    #importing the CSV object
    $csvFile = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath 

    #iteration over each elm in the CSV 
    foreach ($elm in $csvFile) {
        [xml]$file = Get-Content -Path("$updatedFilePath\$updatedFileName.xml");
        $node = $file.SelectSingleNode($elm.xpath);
        $node.model = $elm.model
        $file.Save("$updatedFilePath\$updatedFileName.xml")  
    }

}
```

Comment: You go through great length to create a new XML file, but then you keep overwriting the same input file?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the various incidental aspects aside, here's the gist of your task, which involves saving the output file only *once*:

- Note:

  - An `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance, even if loaded from a particular file with `.Load()`, has no file identity as such, and saving it to a file always requires specifying an explicit output file path. Thus, you can simply load from the original file, perform in-memory modifications of the document, and then `.Save()` the modified document to an output file of choice.
  - Your sample data had various typos (e.g. "Corola") and variations in case ("camry"), which have been corrected. Note that XML - unlike PowerShell - is case-*sensitive*.
  - The code issues a warning if an XPath query read from the CSV file yields no results.

```bash
# Create a sample XML file.
@'
<vehicle>
    <brand model="Corolla">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country> 
    <year>2021</year>

    <brand model="RAV4">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2021</year>
  
    
    <brand model="Camry">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2019</year>

    <brand model="Sienna">Toyota</brand>
    <country>Japan</country>
    <year>2016</year>

</vehicle>
'@ | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 sample-in.xml

# Load it into an XML DOM.
# Note the use of Conver-Path, to ensure that a *full path* is
# passed to the .Load() method.
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path sample-in.xml))

# Create and parse sample CSV (in memory)
$csv = @'
model,xpath
Highlander,/vehicle/brand[@model='Corolla']
Hatchback,/vehicle/brand[@model='RAV4']
Crown,/vehicle/brand[@model='Camry']
GR86,/vehicle/brand[@model='Sienna']
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Loop over all CSV rows and perform the desired subsitutions.
$csv | ForEach-Object {
  try {
    # Look up the target element by the XPath query stored in the CSV's 'xpath'
    # property (column), and assign the value of the 'model' CSV property
    # to the 'model' XML attribute.
    $xml.SelectSingleNode($_.xpath).model = $_.model
  }
  catch {
    Write-Warning "No element found for XPath query: $($_.xpath)"
  }
}

# Save the modified XML DOM to a new file.
# Again, be sure to use a full path.
$xml.Save((Join-Path $PWD sample-out.xml))
```

`sample-out.xml` now contains the following - note the changed model names:

```xml
<vehicle>
  <brand model="Highlander">Toyota</brand>
  <country>Japan</country>
  <year>2021</year>
  <brand model="Hatchback">Toyota</brand>
  <country>Japan</country>
  <year>2021</year>
  <brand model="Crown">Toyota</brand>
  <country>Japan</country>
  <year>2019</year>
  <brand model="GR86">Toyota</brand>
  <country>Japan</country>
  <year>2016</year>
</vehicle>
```